# how to create 0-1 matrix from probability matrix

Tags: numpy, matrix, random

(In any language) For a research project, I am stuck on how to convert a matrix P of probability values to a matrix A such that A_ij = 1 with probability P_ij and 0 otherwise? I have looked through various random number generator documentations, but have been unable to figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

```
In [11]: p = np.random.uniform(size=(5,5))

In [12]: p
Out[12]:
array([[ 0.45481883,  0.21242567,  0.3124863 ,  0.00485797,  0.31970718],
       [ 0.91995847,  0.29907277,  0.59154085,  0.85847147,  0.13227595],
       [ 0.91914631,  0.5495813 ,  0.58648856,  0.08037582,  0.23005148],
       [ 0.12464628,  0.70657028,  0.75975869,  0.77632964,  0.24587041],
       [ 0.69259133,  0.183515  ,  0.65500547,  0.19526148,  0.26975325]])

In [13]: a = (p.round(1)==0.7).astype(np.int8)

In [14]: a
Out[14]:
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]], dtype=int8)
```